# Where to find backend print outs on staging/production?

Tags: react-redux, console.log, staging

Usually when I have backend print outs, I just look in the console that's running `npm run dev`. That's for local development, but where do I look for `console.log()` after pushing to staging or production website?

I'm using react-redux with express and specifically don't know where to look when I `console.log()` something in a routes file.

Any help is appreciated; thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that I had to go to heroku. There's a "more" button on the top right that has an option to "view logs" which is where the backend prints out are.